# SeleniumGrid : org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService Build info: version: '3.141.59'

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid, remotewebdriver

Thats how I started : Hub command : java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role hub
Node Command : java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="\Users\rachitamittal\eclipse-workspace\firstjavaproject\drivers\chromedriver.exe" -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role node -port 5556 -hub "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub" -browser browserName=chrome,maxInstances=3
I have first only created a single node.
MY program :

@Test

public void remotetester() throws MalformedURLException

{

DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();

cap.setBrowserName("chrome");

cap.setPlatform(Platform.MAC);

RemoteWebDriver driver=new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"),cap);

driver.get("https://www.google.com/");

driver.manage().window().maximize();

driver.close();

}

Error :
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService

Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'

System info: host: '///////////', ip: '/////////////////', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.15.4', java.version: '14.0.1'

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Take a tour and get your first badge-https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

Hope so you are doing great and you are safe. The problem is the webdriver path is incorrect. I believe that you have missed to method drive i.e C: in your web driver path.

If you are new and do not know how to configure the selenium grid in the local system then you can use the below utility for the automatic configuration.
https://github.com/frostyaxe/Talongrid

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however I am doing this on MAC OS.

Comment: Oh. Then chromedriver file is incorrect. I can see that you are passing the .exe path and Mac os does not support exe. Please download the chromedriver compatible to macos